# Rails—mysqldump error when migrating

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I'm using Rails 4.0, every time I run a migration I get this error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'regan'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
Could not dump the database structure. Make sure `mysqldump` is in your PATH and check the command output for warnings.
```

I think the migrations are still working ok, but I'm getting a lot of failing tests (I just received this project already built).

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have the users password setup in the `database.yml` file. The common scenario is that you setup a password in the mysql installation and now not providing it.

Your `database.yml` file should look some thing like this.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <my db>
  username: <my user>
  password: <my password>
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

Comment: the weird thing is, I don't have any user or password field in my db setup... Also, my default user doesn't use a password